# Change the random draw line here for a mouseListener draw

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

im working on a "paint" program. So far, i have a GUI with 1 button "Ligne" and one drawable panel. in my class Paint_Dessin, theres a method call TracerLigne(). this method draw line folowing a random patern. What i want to do is put a mouselistener so x1,y1 = click1 and x2,y2 = click 2. this is my code. Thank you (sorry for the french comment)

```
//cree une fenetre  
public class QUESTION {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Paint_GUI test2 = new Paint_GUI();
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Paint_GUI extends JFrame {
    //Panels contenant tout les bouton de mon interface  

    private JPanel panelBtn;
    //Bar d'outil Btn  
    private JButton BtnTracerLigne;
    //créer l'objet Paint_Dessin  
    private Paint_Dessin espaceDessin = new Paint_Dessin();

    public Paint_GUI() {
        final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 650;
        final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 450;

        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Paint v.2.0");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Appeler la methode qui construit la barre de BTN.  
        buildPanelBtn();
        add(panelBtn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(espaceDessin, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Afficher la fenetre.  
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildPanelBtn() {
        BtnTracerLigne = new JButton("Ligne");
        BtnTracerLigne.addActionListener(new LigneListener());

        // Creer le panel.  
        panelBtn = new JPanel();
        // Ajouter les composantes au label  
        panelBtn.add(BtnTracerLigne);
    }

    private class LigneListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            espaceDessin.TracerLigne();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

class Paint_Dessin extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2110723486099015303L;
    private static final Random RAND = new Random();
    private BufferedImage buffer = null;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // cleanup du composant  
        g2.drawImage(getBuffer(), null, 0, 0);
    }

    public void TracerLigne() {
        final Graphics2D g2 = getBuffer().createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // dessin la ligne au pif dans l'espace visible  
        final int x1 = RAND.nextInt(500); // position en X1  
        final int y1 = RAND.nextInt(500); // position en Y1  
        final int x2 = RAND.nextInt(500); // position en X2  
        final int y2 = RAND.nextInt(500); // position en Y2  
        g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        g2.fill(line);
        repaint();
    }

    private BufferedImage getBuffer() {
        if (buffer == null) {
            buffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cleaned up your question.  Next time please post the source code formatted correctly.  When you paste the code, select it in the window and hit the code button (binary icon).  It will indent it four spaces, leading to the page rendering it as sourcecode.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you'll need to add a MouseListener to your painting JPanel (and this can be coded in a single class that extends MouseAdapter).  Then you would override mousePressed and mouseReleased (if those are the methods desired), and in those methods get the mouse position Point from the MouseEvent object passed into it. You will then use the values of the Points to draw a line in your BufferedImage.  My guess is that you will want to get the starting point on mousePressed and the end point on mouseReleased and then draw the line in the buffer after mouseReleased.  You would need a MouseMotionListener (again the MouseAdapter class above would work for this) if you need to draw a line dynamically on mouseDragged.

Check out the tutorials for excellent sample code and explanations: [How To Write a MouseListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

The semi-pseudocode for doing this is something like:

```
// assuming a private inner class
private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      // get your starting point from e, the MouseEvent and store it in variable
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      // get your end point from e, the MouseEvent
      // get the Graphics object from the BufferedImage
      // set the color
      // set rendering hints for antialiasing if desired
      // draw your line using the starting and end points
      // **** dispose your graphics object **** don't forget!
      // repaint your JPanel
   }
}
```